# Move table cells or list items to second row depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables, fluid-layout

My question is simple.

First off, take a look at this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8Nr/

All I have is a very simple table with some padding, borders, text-alignment.

If you visit the jsFiddle above, you can increase the width of the results window and all of the table items will site comfortably. However, if you decrease the width of said window, I want the table cells to move the the second row in order so that side-scrolling isn't required.

I don't mind using `<ul><li>` for this instead of tables, but I do want to be able to do this.

If anyone is familiar with a solution, please let me know. I don't mind using jQuery/JS/CSS, but I'm not familiar with much else.

### Update

Here's the updated jsFiddle with working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8Nr/3/

Comment: That's a navigation menu, not a `table`. Consider using a `ul`, or similar.

Comment: @David Thomas Not at all. It's a navigation menu.

Comment: And at what width do you want content to drop to the next line? All of them, or just wrap (as paragraph text would)?

Comment: Just wrap. I'm assuming that makes it harder in a table, that's why I said `<ul><li>` is fine as well.

Comment: Table rows don't wrap. Imagine how hard true tabular data would be to read if the rows wrapped.

Comment: @j08691 I realize that; that's why I'm wondering if there's a jQuery solution where I can create a second/third/... row and move cells according to the width.

Comment: No need for jQuery. You could float list items (or divs or whatever left) or you could use the display:inline-block property to do what you need. Quick example http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Jk8Nr/2/

Comment: It would be trivial to have them wrap at narrower widths, but the question is do you need the nav to stretch the full width regardless of what width the browser is open when they're displayed inline like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the other posters suggesting you use a list instead of a table. You can then use a media query to force a wrap at a given device-width if you want that level of control over the layout. Here's an example setting a breakpoint at 600px (markup then css)

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Gallery</li>
        <li>Location</li>
        <li>Rates</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</header>​

ul {
    width:100%;
}
li {
    width:118px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    padding:5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    border-bottom:none; 
    text-align:center;            
}
li:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

@media (min-width:600px) {
    li {
        clear:none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #000;        
        border-right:none;
    }
    li:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8Nr/8/
​

Answer (score 2):

add

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

to your TABLE-style

and

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your TD/TH-Style...

cheers.

Comment: :D okay ;) i'll be more slow in future... :P

Comment: and now? i got a downvote of all these "semantically"-correct-guys which did not read your question correctly... UL/LI or OL/LI is the more clean solution, but you WANTED to achieve this Tables, CORRECT?

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but just because we suggest using a list rather than a table, doesn't mean we didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: I agree with the down vote actually. Why use tables if you're going to change the display to inline-block?

Comment: because he EXPLICITLY WANTS IT?!

Comment: The poster did state "I don't mind using <ul><li> for this instead of tables" - which would be a better solution. That said, what you gave him works, so I'll give you a vote.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using a list for this, ordered or unordered as you see fit; if only because of the semantics (a navigation menu is a list of pages to which you may wish to go), whereas a `table` should present data in a tabular format. That said, I'd propose:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Gallery</li>
        <li>Location</li>
        <li>Rates</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</header>​
```

With the CSS:

```
header ul {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0; /* to remove the white-space gaps between the li elements */
    text-align: center; /* to center the list, amend as appropriate */
}

header ul li {
    font-size: 16px; /* to explicitly reset the font-size and
                        override that of the parent */
    display: inline-block; /* to allow for wrapping */
    width: 19%; /* a baseline width, if the monitor is wide enough to allow it */
    min-width: 7em; /* a minimum width, if the 19% of the width of the ul is less than
                       7em, the li elements will wrap to the next line, rather than
                       becoming too small to be functional */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* To explicitly include the border in the width
                                       of the element */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jk8Nr/4/).

Comment: That is the correct way OP should go, also if he want to arrange li's one below another as soon as it overflows, he can use media queries to make li's block display for smaller screens. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use some semantic markup like this:

```
<header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</header>
```

And then use css media queries to style your page for smaller screens.

```
header ul {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

header ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
    min-width: 7em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media all and (max-width: 564px) and (min-width: 100px){
    header ul li {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8Nr/6/